# How to build a finite state machine

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question that i have been working for a while for now.
This is what i put down for my regular expression: a (a+b)* baa

This is the question is asking: Construct the state digraph (including accept states) of a Moore machine that accepts all strings that start with b and end with baa. The input alphabet is A = {a, b}.

Comment: Don't you want a b at the beginning of your regex, not an a?

Comment: you are right, that is a type from my part. but do you know how to build a fsm from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_0$ be the starting state. The first thing you need to do is make sure that the first letter is a $b$, so we'll have the rules:
$$S_0 \overset{a}{\to} S_1, S_0\overset{b}{\to} S_2$$
and if the machine is in state $S_1$ it will remain there. If the machine gets to state $S_2$, all we need to do is make it so that the accepting state is reached after any occurrence of the sequence $baa$, so that if the string ends with such a sequence the machine will be in an accepting state. Thus we want transition rules
$$S_2\overset{b}{\to} S_3, S_3\overset{a}{\to} S_4, S_4\overset{a}{\to} S_5$$
with $S_5$ the accepting state. If we run into a letter which is *not* part of the sequence $baa$, we want to restart our search for $baa$, which we do by returning to the state $S_2$. Thus we add the rules
$$S_2\overset{a}{\to} S_2, S_3\overset{b}{\to} S_2, S_4\overset{b}{\to} S_2, S_5\overset{a,b}{\to} S_2$$

Comment: This is excellent. thank you. Could you explain why S1 never goes anywhere? , if you were to build a transition table, The S1 would not go anywhere. meaning that in the table, S1 would be empty.

Comment: @user138568 I mean you should force $S_1$ to never go anywhere, e.g. with the transition rules $S_1\overset{a}{\to} S_1$ and $S_1\overset{b}{\to} S_1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. This helps a lot.